# Почему нет запятых перед повторяющимеся И

Tags: пунктуация

> Частокол был обвешан связками сушеных груш и яблок и проветривающимися коврами.

Почему в предложении перед каждой И нет запятых? Ведь схема предложения напоминает слудующую: `* ,И * ,И * ,И ...` То есть, однородные члены соединены повторяущимся союзом И.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В примере, который Вы приводите, союзы ***и*** нельзя считать повторяющимся,  так как они объединяют разные члены предложения: 
    Груш и яблок
   2 Связками и коврами
Ср.: ...Везде ее встречали весело ***и*** дружелюбно и уверяли ее, что она хорошая, ми­лая, редкая (Ч.) Здесь союзы ***и*** нельзя считать повторяющимися, так как они объединяют разные члены предложения (весело и дружелюбно, встречали и уверяли); это одиночные союзы, объединяющие; пары раз­ных членов предложения.

***Подробнее см.: Полный академический справочник.***

Answer (score 1):

1. Груш и яблок
2. Связками и коврами

Где повторяющийся союз?!

Answer (score 1):

Это не повторяющиеся союзы. Первое "И" соединяет груши и яблоки (связки чего?), второе - связки и ковры (обвешан чем?). 
Повторяющимися же считаются союзы, соединяющие однородные члены (два и более), т.е. как минимум **отвечающие на один вопрос** и одну функцию в предложении - при ёго грамматическом разборе.